# Autolayout constraints in TextField of an outlineView

Tags: autolayout, nstableview, nsoutlineview, appkit

last night a have an autolayout issue. I was googling and try to find something similar in SO. Even the apple doc doesn't point me to the right direction. Maybe my search terms are completely wrong.
Maybe you guys can bring some light into my darkness.

I added a NSOutlineView in storyboard and added some constraints to the NSTableCellView. As you can see, i added a trailing space to Superview of 50:

[image: Storyboard]

My example code adds some foo's and bar's into the outlineView by identifyer:

```
func outlineView(outlineView: NSOutlineView, viewForTableColumn tableColumn: NSTableColumn?, item: AnyObject) -> NSView? {
    if tableColumn?.identifier == "NAME_COLUMN" {
        cell = outlineView.makeViewWithIdentifier("NAME_COLUMN", owner: self) as NSTableCellView
        cell.textField!.stringValue = "foo"
        cell.textField!.editable = true
        cell.textField!.delegate = self

    } else
    if tableColumn?.identifier == "VALUE_COLUMN" {
        cell = outlineView.makeViewWithIdentifier("VALUE_COLUMN", owner: self) as NSTableCellView
        cell.textField!.stringValue = "bar"
        cell.textField!.editable = true
        cell.textField!.delegate = self
    }

    return cell
}
```

But the trailing space will not show up in my running application!

[image]

I even try to set the cell display:

```
cell.needsDisplay = true
cell.needsLayout = true
cell.needsUpdateConstraints = true
```

or - according to someone on the internet - add "requiresConstraintBasedLayout":

```
class func requiresConstraintBasedLayout() -> Bool {
    return true
}
```

but all without luck. The trailing space do not appears and the bar's on the right side border looks awful.

How do i use a TableViewCell inside a OutlineView with a trailing space?

Thanks a lot for any kind of hint.

ps

Comment: That's a lot of UI, what trailing space, maybe you circle it?

Comment: Hm, no. I did a second project with an NSOutlineView and a constraint from the textField to the outer view will only appear in the storyboard, but not in the application. The textField (right indented) is always on the right side without any space to the right border.